# Javascript sum of arrays and average

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with getting the sum of two arrays and combining their averages while rounding off.

I don't want to hardcode but rather pass two random arrays.  
so here is the code but it keeps returning **NaN**

```js
function sumAverage(arr) {
  var result = 0;
  // Your code here
  // set an array
  arr = [];
  a = [];
  b = [];
  arr[0] = a;
  arr[1] = b;

  var sum = 0;

  // compute sum of elements in the array
  for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    sum += a[j];
  }

  // get the  average of elements in the array
  var total = 0;
  total += sum / a.length;


  var add = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    add += b[i];

  var math = 0;
  math += add / b.length;

  result += math + total;

  Math.round(result);

  return result;
}
console.log(sumAverage([
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9]
]));
```

Comment: Hi @Martin have you done any of your own debugging here? Narrowed down the issue to a specific area of your function?

Comment: You reset `arr` to an empty array at the beginning of your function. Don't do that.

Comment: `b.length` is always `0`. Browsers have great debugging tools these days. Set a breakpoint, step through the code and inspect the values of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do it a bit more functionally, you could do something like this:

```js
function sumAverage(arrays) {
  const average = arrays.reduce((acc, arr) => {
    const total = arr.reduce((total, num) => total += num, 0);
    return acc += total / arr.length;
  }, 0);
  
  return Math.round(average);
}

console.log('sum average:', sumAverage([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this method..this kind of issues sometimes occured for me.

For example

```
 var total = 0;
 total = total + sum / a.length;
```

And every concat use this method..

Comment: So you're saying to use `total = total + 1` instead of `total += 1`? Am I understanding correctly? I don't see much difference between your suggestion and what the OP is already using... (not my DV)

Answer (score 0):

Basically I see a mistake here:
     `arr[0] = a; arr[1] = b;`

That should be
    `a= arr[0]; b= arr[1];`

and then remove:
             `arr = [];`

---

I suggest you write your function like this:

```
function sum(arr) {
var arr1 = arr[0]
var sum1 = 0;
arr1.map(function(e){sum1+=e});
var arr2 = arr[1]
var sum2 = 0;
arr2.map(function(e){sum2+=e});
return Math.round(sum1/arr1.length + sum2/arr2.length);
}
```

Comment: This actually works, i am glad it wasn't a major issue as i thought.

Comment: Happy to help you Martin, don't forget to mark it as solved

Comment: @martin You wanted sum of averages right? Given your data the answer should be 11, which is sum of 3.5 and 7.5 isn't it?

Comment: @PankajShukla: You're right, let me update my suggestion

Comment: @R.Saban You are passing two arrays to the function. OP is passing just one nested array.

Comment: @PankajShukla: You're right, I updated it again. However I would personally prefer to use 2 args if I expect my array to contain only 2 elements.

Comment: I believe @Sophie 's answer should be the accepted one. It uses the reduce function, which is exactly what is needed here, though less readable for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning the value [] with the same name as the argument? This works, see [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zg68yfex/)

```
function sumAverage(arr) {
  var result = 0;

  //arr = [];
  //a = [];
  //b = [];
  a = arr[0];
  b = arr[1];

  var sum = 0;

  // compute sum of elements in the array
  for(var j = 0; j < a.length; j++ ){
    sum += a[j] ;
  }

// get the  average of elements in the array
var total = 0;
total += sum / a.length;

var add = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    add += b[i];

  var math = 0;
  math += add / b.length;
  result += math + total;

Math.round(result);
  return result;
}
document.write(sumAverage([[2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are emptying arr by saying `arr = []`.

Later, you are iterating over `a` which is empty too.
Again when you say `total += sum / a.length;`, sum is 0 and a.length is 0 so 0/0 becomes NaN. Similarly for `math`. Adding Nan to NaN is again NaN and that's what you get.

Solution is to not empty passed arr and modify your code like below:

```js
function sumAverage(arr) {
  var result = 0;
  // Your code here
  // set an array
  //arr = [];
  //a = [];
  //b = [];
  a = arr[0];
  b = arr[1];

  var sum = 0;

  // compute sum of elements in the array
  for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    sum += a[j];
  }

  // get the  average of elements in the array
  var total = 0;
  total = sum / a.length;


  var add = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    add += b[i];

  var math = 0;
  math = add / b.length;

  result = math + total;

  result = Math.round(result);

  return result;
}
console.log(sumAverage([
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9]
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, you reset your arguments...

Use the variable "arguments" for dynamic function parameters.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use two nested loops, one for the outer array and one for the inner arrays. Then sum values, calculate the average and add averages.

```js
function sumAverage(array) {
    var result = 0,
        sum,
        i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            sum += array[i][j];
        }
        result += Math.round(sum / array[i].length);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(sumAverage([[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]])); // 12
```